# How do we control application type versions retention?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We want to execute external integration tests and manually call a rollback if something is wrong.

We're using the 'Service Fabric Application Deployment' task in Team Services (VSTS) and it seems to only keep the latest in the cluster.

*Cluster --> Applications --> [Application], and then under Essentials. Only one row item is listed which shows the latest version.*

*Also, attempting `Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade` results in 'Application type and version not found.'*

How do we alter the behaviour of previous version retention of application types? (And what is the default?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer to your question, but I do offer this thought:

While I understand there may be a valid use case out there for trying to do this, I think a more accepted approach is to set up a test environment that matches production very closely. Deploy to test and test the heck out of it before approving the deployment to production.

One of the main selling points of Service Fabric is its ability to be so redundant, yet with your proposed workflow you are deploying code to that environment in which you're not entirely confident in. I think that really goes against what Service Fabric offers you.

Since you will be testing it so thoroughly on the Test environment, hopefully anything you end up finding in Production is small enough to be fixed through a patch a few hours later or however fast you can fix it.